# Prove $\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}dx=\ln2+H_n-H_{2n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, harmonic-numbers

How to prove

> $$\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}dx=\ln2+H_n-H_{2n}$$

I used this identity to solve some advanced harmonic series but I didn't provide a proof so I see that it's worth a post so that we can use it as a reference for future solutions if needed. Here is my approach and **would like to see alternative ones**.

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}dx&=\ln2-2n\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\ln(1+x)dx\tag1\\
&=\ln2-2n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\int_0^1 x^{2n+k-1}dx\tag2\\
&=\ln2+2n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k(k+2n)}\tag3\\
&=\ln2+4n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2k(2k+2n)}-2n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k+2n)}\tag4\\
&=\ln2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n}{k(k+n)}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{k(k+2n)}\tag5\\
&=\ln2+H_n-H_{2n}\tag6
\end{align}

---

**Explanation:**

1) Apply integration by parts

2) Write $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}x^{k}$

3) Use the rule $\int_0^1 x^ndx=\frac1{n+1}$

4) $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k f(k)=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(2k)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)$

5) Simplify

6) Use $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n}{k(k+n)}$

---

A good application for this identity is the following problem proposed by Cornel:

$$\zeta(3)=\frac43\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2H_{2n}-H_n)(H_n-H_{2n}+\ln2)}{n}$$

If we multiply both sides of our identity by $\frac{2H_{2n}-H_n}{n}$ then sum up from $n= 1$ to $\infty$ we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2H_{2n}-H_n)(H_n-H_{2n}+\ln2)}{n}=\int_0^1\frac1{1+x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{n}(2H_{2n}-H_n)dx\\=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)dx=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1+x}dx=\frac34\zeta(3)$$

where [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3250483) $\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n}(2H_{2n}-H_n)$ was used in our calculations.

---

Another application is calculating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nH_{n/2}}{n^3}$:

From our proof above, we can see that

$$\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\ln(1+x)dx=\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{2n}$$

Replace $2n$ by $n$ then multiply both sides by $\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ and sum up we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^3}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nH_{n/2}}{n^3}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n^2}dx\\=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{x}dx=-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(-1)=-\frac12\left(-\frac12\zeta(2)\right)^2=-\frac5{16}\zeta(4)$$

I managed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3219475) to prove

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^3}=2\operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{11}4\zeta(4)+\frac74\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{12}\ln^42$$

Thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nH_{n/2}}{n^3}=2\operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{39}{16}\zeta(4)+\frac74\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{12}\ln^42$$

Answer (score 9):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1x^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-x)^k\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\int_0^1x^{2n+k}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2n+k+1}\\
&=\sum_{j=2n+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}j-\sum_{j=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}j\\
&=\ln{(2)}+H_n-H_{2n}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice series manipulation

Comment: In fact the same method provides us with$$\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x=(-1)^n(\ln{(2)}+H_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}-H_n)$$

Answer (score 5):

We have using only integration of rational functions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1
\frac{x^{2n}}{x+1}\; dx
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{x^{2n}+x}{x+1}\; dx
-
\int_0^1
\frac{x}{x+1}\; dx
\\
&=
\int_0^1
\Big(x^{2n-1}-x^{2n-2}+\dots- x^4 + x^3 - x^2 + x\Big)\; dx
-
\int_0^1
\frac{x}{x+1}\; dx
\\
&=
\left(\frac 1{2n}-\frac 1{2n-1}+\dots -\frac 15+\frac 14-\frac 13+\frac 12\right)-1+\log 2
\\
&=
\log 2 - H_{2n}+2\left( \frac 12+\frac 14+\dots+\frac 1{2n}\right)
\\
&=
\log 2 - H_{2n}+H_n\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: interesting solution.. thank you (+1).

Answer (score 4):

A common proof:

\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}\,dx-H_n+H_{2n}&=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}dx+\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n}-1}{1+x}dx-\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx+\\
&\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{2x(1-x^{2n})}{1-x^2}\,dx\\
\end{align}In the last integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}\,dx-H_n+H_{2n}&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\ln 2
\end{align}

NB:
For $n\geq 1$, integer,
\begin{align}H_n=\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx\end{align}
Proof by induction:
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{1-x}\,dx&=1\\
&=H_1\\
\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}dx&=\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx+\int_0^1 \frac{x^n-x^{n+1}}{1-x}dx \\
&=H_n+\int_0^1 \frac{x^n(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx\\
&H_n+\int_0^1 x^n\,dx\\
&=H_n+\frac{1}{n+1}\\
&=H_{n+1}
\end{align}

Comment: nice solution (+1) thank you

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 3):

A magical solution by Cornel as usual:

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}dx&=\ln2-2n\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\ln(1+x)dx\tag1\\
&=\ln2-2n\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\ln(1-x^2)dx+2n\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\ln(1-x)dx\tag2\\
&=\ln2-n\int_0^1y^{n-1}\ln(1-y)dy+2n\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\ln(1-x)dx\tag3\\
&=\ln2-n\left(-\frac{H_n}{n}\right)+2n\left(-\frac{H_{2n}}{2n}\right)\tag4\\
&=\ln2+H_n-H_{2n}
\end{align}

---

**Explanation:**

1) Apply integration by parts

2) Write $\ln(1+x)=\ln(1-x^2)-\ln(1-x)$

3) Set $x^2=y$ for the first integral

4) Use $\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)dx=-\frac{H_n}{n}$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x =
\ln\pars{2} + H_{n} - H_{2n}}:\ {\Large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n} - x^{2n + 1}\over 1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n} - x^{n + 1/2}\over 1 - x}
\pars{{1 \over 2}\,x^{-1/2}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\pars{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over 2}\pars{H_{n} - H_{n - 1/2}}
\end{align}

where I used the
[Harmonic Number Euler Integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).

---

With the
[Harmonic Number Multiplication Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Multiplication_formulas):
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over 2}\braces{\vphantom{\Large A}H_{n} - \bracks{\vphantom{\large A}2H_{2n} - H_{n} - 2\ln\pars{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &
\bbx{\ln\pars{2} + H_{n} - H_{2n}}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice solution Felix (+1).