# About Harmonic Numbers and a sequence in OEIS

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, harmonic-numbers, oeis

I'd been looking for a series in OEIS and the one that fits better (resembles, at least) is one in this link in Examples: http://oeis.org/A082687. There, as we can see, it is equal to

$$H'(2n) = H(2n)-H(n) = \cdots  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$

Also, I know that $H$ represents harmonic numbers. However here is the thing: I'm confused, since the harmonic numbers should be **only** numbers not a series. Then I searched at Wiki about these "harmonic series", but they seem not to exist. Bellow (1), there is something about Hilbert Matrix, maybe that is it, but I'm not sure as I do not even know what this is.

Could someone give me a clue about what these $H$s are and/or tell what (1) means?

Thanks

Comment: The OEIS entry says that the $n$th element of the sequence is the *numerator* of $H'(2n)$, which is indeed a number. The number $H'(2n)$ is defined in terms of a series, but it's still a number.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it! So basically the series is: $\sum_0^\infty H'(2n)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would write the expression you give in (1):
$$\overline H_{2n} = H_{2n} - H_n. \tag2$$
Here $H_n$ denotes the $n$th *harmonic number* $\sum_{k = 1}^n 1/k$ while $\overline H_n$ denotes the $n$th *skew-harmonic number* $\sum_{k = 1}^n (-1)^{k + 1}/k$.

In proving (2), we have
\begin{align}
\overline H_{2n} &= \sum_{k = 1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k}\\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{2n}\\
&= 1 + \left (\frac{1}{2} - 1 \right ) + \frac{1}{3} + \left (\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \right ) + \frac{1}{5} + \left (\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{3} \right ) + \cdots\\
&\qquad \cdots + \frac{1}{2n - 1} + \left (\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{n} \right )\\
&= \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} \right ) - \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} \right )\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}\\
&= H_{2n} - H_n,
\end{align}
as required to prove.

Checking that we indeed get the first few terms in OEIS A082687, since
\begin{align}
\overline H_2 &= \sum_{k = 1}^2 \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k} = \frac{1}{2}\\
\overline H_4 &= \sum_{k = 1}^4 \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k} = \frac{7}{12}\\
\overline H_6 &= \sum_{k = 1}^6 \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k} = \frac{37}{60}\\
\overline H_8 &= \sum_{k = 1}^8 \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k} = \frac{533}{840}
\end{align}
and selecting the numerators for each of these quantities we have the sequence: $\{1, 7, 37, 533, \ldots\}$ as desired.

Comment: The series manipulation is not clear to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Ali Shather I have added an extra line in my proof of $\overline H_{2n} = H_{2n} - H_n$. Each term in the sum containing an even denominator has been rewritten in brackets and hopefully now shows how the (finite) series can be manipulated into the required form.

Comment: Fine, I got it! However, if I want to make a series then it would be like: $\sum_0^\infty \bar{H}(2k)$ or $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$

Comment: Pretty clear now thanks. I think the last second term not needed .

Comment: @Mr. N Yes, so $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \overline H_{2n} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sum_{k = 1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k},$$ which diverges.

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

$$\overline{H}_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}\int_0^1 x^{k-1}\ dx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-x)^{k-1}\ dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1+x}\ dx=\ln2-\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}\ dx=H_{2n}-H_n$$

where the last result follows from [$\int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}dx=\ln2+H_n-H_{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427776/prove-int-01-fracx2n1xdx-ln2h-n-h-2n).

Comment: Great answer, did not know that. Interesting how $ln2$ is related to. How did you transform a part of the summation into na integral?

Comment: @Mr. N thank you. Converting to integral is the same idea of converting $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\ dx$. Such transformation is  commonly used in harmonic series and logarithmic integrals.