# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{1}{k+r}=\sum_{k=1}^{2r}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

How to prove that

> $$\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{1}{k+r}=\sum_{k=1}^{2r}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\tag1$$

We know that both sides are equal to $H_{2r}-H_r$ but I am trying to convert the left side to the right side using **only series manipulations and without going through $H_{2r}-H_r$**

There is nothing I could try but we know that
$$\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{1}{k+r}=\sum_{k=1+r}^{2r}\frac{1}{k}$$

What next? Thank you.

---

By the way, its easy to prove it using integration,

$$\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{1}{k+r}=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^r x^{k+r-1}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{x^r-x^{2r}}{1-x}\ dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{2n}-(1-x^r)}{1-x}\ dx=H_{2r}-H_r\tag2$$

and we proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3550444)

$$\overline{H}_{2r}=\sum_{k=1}^{2r}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=H_{2r}-H_r\tag3$$

Hence by $(2)$ and $(3)$ , $(1)$ is proved

Comment: Your linked question gives a series-manipulation proof that the right-hand side is $H_{2r}-H_r$, and the left-hand side is simply $$\sum_{k=r+1}^{2r} \frac1k = \sum_{k=1}^{2r} \frac1k - \sum_{k=1}^{r} \frac1k = H_{2r}-H_r$$ by definition. You can just combine the two computations to get the proof you want.

Comment: @Greg Martin I think you misunderstood or my wording was confusing. I want to convert the left side to the right side using series manipulation without going through $H_{2r}-H_r$

Comment: Yes. The linked answer has the computation$$\text{\rm (RHS of (1))}{} = A = B=C=D=E=H_{2r}-H_r,$$and in my previous comment is the computation $$\text{\rm (LHS of (1))} = F = H_{2r}-H_r.$$ Therefore the proof you are looking for is $$\text{\rm(LHS of (1))} = F = E=D=C=B=A=\text{\rm(RHS of (1))}.$$ (Indeed $E$ and $F$ are the same expression, but that's not relevant.)

Comment: @Greg Martin  I edited my question. I think its less confusing now.

Comment: I think induction will work.

Comment: @GregMartin let's see what the others say. Thanks though.

Comment: @ Ali Shather Nice problem (I would do it inductively). Just a remark: it is interesting that the equation does not hold for the analytic continuations of both sides to real $r$ unless $r$ is integer. Indeed, the closed form of the lhs is $H_{2r}-H_{r}$, and that of the lhs is $(-1)^{2 r+1} \Phi (-1,1,2 r+1)+\log (2)$. Now due to the facor $(-1)^{2r+1}$ the rhs becomes  complex for non integer $r$ so that the equality is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another direct proof.

The difference between r.h.s. and l.h.s is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2r}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{1}{k+r}
\\=\sum_{k=1}^{2r}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}-\sum_{k=r+1}^{2r}\frac{1}{k}
\\=\sum_{k=1}^{2r}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{2r}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{r}\frac{1}{k}
\\=\sum_{k=1}^{2r}\frac{1}{k}\left((-1)^{k-1}-1\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{r}\frac{1}{k}
\\\overset{k\to 2m}=\sum_{m=1}^{r}\frac{1}{2m}\left(-2\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{r}\frac{1}{k}=0$$

Hence l.h.s = r.h.s. QED

Comment: Thank you Dr. but I said in the question that I need to manipulate the LHS to get the RHS. To be more clear I want to see manipulations like Cauchy product, exchanging double series , manipulating the series boundaries and other tricks.

Comment: @ Ali Shather Sorry, but a closer look at my exposition will show you that I mainly manipulated your LHS, as requested in the OP.

Comment: Sorry Wolf just saw your reply... actually your solution is the one I'm looking for. Perfect +1

Answer (score 2):

Let

$u(r)
=\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{1}{k+r}\\
v(r)
=\sum_{k=1}^{2r}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}
$.

To show that
$u(r) = v(r)$
it is enough to show that
$u(1) = v(1)$
and
$u(r+1)-u(r)
=v(r+1)-v(r)
$.

$u(1)
=\frac12$
and
$v(1)
=1-\frac12
=\frac12$.

$v(r+1)-v(r)
=\sum_{k=2r+1}^{2r+2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}
=\frac1{2r+1}-\frac1{2r+2}
=\frac1{(2r+1)(2r+2)}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
u(r+1)-u(r)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{r+1}\frac{1}{k+r+1}-\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{1}{k+r}\\
&=\sum_{k=r+2}^{2r+2}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=r+1}^{2r}\frac{1}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=r+2}^{2r}\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2r+1}+\frac{1}{2r+2}-(\frac{1}{r+1}+\sum_{k=r+2}^{2r}\frac{1}{k})\\
&=\frac{1}{2r+1}+\frac{1}{2r+2}-\frac{1}{r+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2r+1}-\frac{1}{2r+2}\\
&=\frac{1}{(2r+1)(2r+2)}\\
&=v(r+1)-v(r)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: @ marty cohen +1 for the inductive proof. I had the same idea, but later ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out by @Greg Martin, one way to get the result you desire using only manipulations of series would be to essentially run the proof of the result I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548270/about-harmonic-numbers-and-a-sequence-in-oeis/3548292#3548292) in reverse.

Starting with $\sum_{k = 1}^r \frac{1}{k + r}$ reindexing $k \mapsto k - r$ we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^r \frac{1}{k + r} &= \sum_{k = r + 1}^{2r} \frac{1}{k}\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{2r} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}\\
&= \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2r - 1} + \frac{1}{2r} \right ) - \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{r} \right )\\
&= 1 + \left (\frac{1}{2} - 1 \right ) + \frac{1}{3} + \left (\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \right ) + \frac{1}{5} + \left (\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{3} \right ) + \cdots\\
&\qquad \cdots + \frac{1}{2n - 1} + \left (\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{n} \right )\\ 
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{2n}\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{2r} \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k},
\end{align}
as desired.

Of course this is just $H_{2r}$ and $H_r$ in disguise. So let us try again starting from the other side.
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{2r} \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k} &= 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2r - 1} - \frac{1}{2r}\\
&= \left (1 - \frac{1}{2} \right ) + \left (\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} \right ) + \cdots + \left (\frac{1}{2r - 1} - \frac{1}{2r} \right )\\
&= \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} - 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \right ) + \left (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} - 2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \right ) + \cdots\\
& \qquad \cdots + \left (\frac{1}{2r - 1} + \frac{1}{2r} - 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2r} \right )\\
&= \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2r - 1} + \frac{1}{2r} \right ) - 2 \left (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2r} \right )\\
&= \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2r - 1} + \frac{1}{2r} \right ) - \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{r} \right )\\
&= \frac{1}{r + 1} + \frac{1}{r + 2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2r}\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^r \frac{1}{k + r},
\end{align}
which is essentially the same thing.

Finally, this identity is known as the *Botez-Catalan identity*.

Comment: Thank you but you went through $H_{2r}-H_r$ which I mentioned to avoid.